# while installing oracle database mobile server Remote server does not listen for requests

Tags: oracle, glassfish

I'm trying to install oracle database mobile server. I followed all the steps in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48200_01/doc.1130/e38579/gsg_install.htm#OLGET411)

my problem is when doing this step 
[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6tB7.jpg)

repository file outputs this error

> Error occurred when starting Glassfish domain "mobileserver" 
>   Deploying mobile located at C:\OraHome_7\mobile\server\admin\repository\mobile on Glassfish Server ...
>   Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:7001]. Is the server up?
>   Unable to get remote commands. 
>   Closest matching local command(s): 
>       help
>   Command deploy failed.
>   Error occurred when deploying application mobile.
>   CLI306 Warning - server is not running.
>   Command stop-domain executed successfully.
>   Glassfish domain "mobileserver" stopped ...

and my server fails to start

here is  my **domain.xml**

```
<network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
        </network-listeners>
```

Any idea what is the problem please help :(

Comment: Restart the Domain Administration Server (DAS) of the specified host and try again. Your admin port should show as `[localhost:4848]` instead of `[localhost:7001]`.

Comment: restarting the domain failed it says that the command either take a long time or the server has failed..

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the installation then. Could be any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the glassfish server 
I re-install it and evry thing works fine